# How to call a class methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am currently learning ES6. While I was playing with the new features, I got stuck at one point. How to call a class method.

So let's say I have a class in one file like below:

```
class Auth {
    checkUserSignedIn() {
       //check user signed in
    }

    signupUser(account) {
       //signup user
    }

    loginUser(account) {
        //login user
    }

    getCurentUser() {
        //Current User
    }
}

module.exports = Auth;
```

and then in some other file, let's say a controller I would like to call these functions.

```
const Auth = require('./auth');
class Controller {
    signupUserUsingEmailAndPass(user) {
        Auth.signupUser(account);

    }

    loginUserUsingEmailAndPass(account) {
            Auth.loginUser(account);
    }

    isUserSignedIn() {
      checkUserSignedIn();
    }
}

module.exports = Controller;
```

But this doesn't work at all. I guess there is something I am not understanding correctly. Any suggestion/advice?

Comment: you need to create an instance of `Auth` to call those member functions. It seems like you don't need to use a class at all there and should just return an object literal with a bunch of functions.

Comment: It sounds very much like you **don't want a `class`** which is only useful for stateful instances.

Comment: @Bergi Well I thought this might be a good approach, seems like it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Javascript classes don't work quite like the module pattern (that it seems) you're used to. When you export `Auth, you're exporting the class definition but you still need to instantiate it.

```
let auth = new Auth()
auth.signupUserUsingEmailAndPass() // or any other function you define
```

In javascript, a class is useful when you want to populate it with data or some sort of state. If you don't want or need that then you can use a module.

Comment: I get an error by following your solution. TypeError: Cannot read property 'methodName()' of undefined

Comment: …or when you actually want a *module*, you just should not use a `class`.

Comment: Okay, methodName was a placeholder. In your case it would be signupUserUsingEmailAndPass or any of the others you've defined. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Methods defined in a class require an instance of that class, i.e. a `new Auth` somewhere.

Your controller should be defined has

```
class Controller {

  constructor(auth) {
    this.auth = auth;
  }
}
```

This approach over the `require('myclass')` allows for you to inject different implementations of your `Auth` class.

Should you not desire an instance of `Auth` for those methods, declare them as static. More on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either instatiate the `Auth`

```
const authorization = new Auth();
```

Possibly inside the file containing the `Auth` class, and just export the instance.

```
export const authorization = new Auth();
```

Or, if You want this methods available outside. You can make the methods `static`. Just add `static` keyword before the method name during method creation.

You can read more about static methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

Comment: I get an error by following your solution. TypeError: Cannot read property 'signupUser()' of undefined

Comment: Which one? Using static method? Or exporting instance of class? It seems the import is undefined. Did you import it using `import { authorization } from ...`?


If You used static method just use it like You was originally. The new instance is not needed.

Comment: static works fine but exporting instance of a class results in an error

Comment: Maybe You exported it as a default, the the brackets `{}` would result in error. Also do only one default export per file. Still, in this case maybe old good object literal would be better than a class.